# Jx Browser 6.23 is slower than 6.21?

Tags: javascript, java, performance, javafx, jxbrowser

I am new to JavaFx and JavaScripting

My JavaFx application (which displays an HTML/JavaScript page) measures performance of different versions of JX Browser.

**It seems that JX bowser 6.23 is slower that 6.21 when I execute the *Run* button manually.**

*What am I doing wrong? What should I do to improve performance.*

**Version (6.23)** - 10 execution times in ms
3879, 3637, 4483, 3583, 3565, 3656, 3748, 3834, 3895, 3799

median 3773.5, average 3807.9, max 4483, min 3565

**Version (6.21)** - 10 execution times in ms
3581, 3326, 3257, 3273, 3217, 3299, 3284, 3304, 3352, 3323

median 3301.5, average 3321.6, max 3581, min 3217

Sample codes as below:

**JavaFX Code**

*sample.fxml*

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane fx:id="pane" fx:controller="sample.Controller"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
</AnchorPane>
```

*Main.java*

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test JX Browser Performance");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1800, 1000));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Controller.java*

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Controller.class);

    @FXML
    public AnchorPane pane;

    public static String pagePath = new File("src/sample/html/testJXBrowserCode.html").getAbsolutePath();;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches(
                "--enable-experimental-canvas-features=true",
                "--num-raster-threads=4",
                "--max-tiles-for-interest-area=512",
                "--disable-web-security",
                "--allow-file-access-from-files",
                "--headless",
                "--remote-debugging-port=9222");

        final Browser browser = new Browser();
        final BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);
        pane.getChildren().add(browserView);

        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(browserView, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(browserView, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(browserView, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(browserView, 0.0);

        final String url = "file://" + pagePath;
        browser.loadURL(url);

    }
}
```

*pom.xml* (For testing the jxbrowser version was switched between 6.21 & 6.23)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>version-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>VersionTest</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxbrowser</artifactId>
            <version>6.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxbrowser-win64</artifactId>
            <version>6.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxbrowser-licence</artifactId>
            <version>6.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>com.google.code.findbugs</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jsr305</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**HTML/JavaScript**

*testJXBrowserCode.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <script src="lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test JX Browser Performance</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <button onclick="run()">Run</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a class="displayText">TEST</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a class="complete"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a class="startTime"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a class="endTime"></a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function run() {
            console.log("run");
            var startTime = Date.now();
            $(".startTime").text("Start time " + startTime);

            for (var i = 0; i < 99999; i++) {
                $(".displayText").text("hello " + i);
                console.log(i);
            }

            var endTime = Date.now();
            $(".endTime").text("Start time " + endTime);

            $(".complete").text("Total time taken " + (endTime - startTime));
        }
    </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If not a single thing changed inside the code, then it's the new version of the browser indeed. Not much you can do to change that. You can however use best practices while coding javascript. Stuff like: Don't update the DOM inside loops. Use document fragments. Provide all object properties at creation instead of adding them ad hoc later. Not using the delete statement. Not using JQuery for things you can do native. And I'm sure Java has best practices like that as well for the Java side of the code.

Comment: I've tried the following benchmark with JxBrowser versions 6.21 and 6.23 https://v8.github.io/web-tooling-benchmark/. It seems for me that results are mostly the same. From 9.72 seconds to 10.23 seconds under Ubuntu 16.04 on my machine.